# Vue not rendering table correctly

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm trying to render the rows of a table where each row is my custom component `<todo-list>`, but the resulting rows get rendered outside of my table. Why is this?

Here's a screenshot of the DOM tree which shows what is happening:

[image: Screenshot]

My view:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <div id="appTest">
                        <div>@{{error}}</div>



                        <table class="table-responsive">
                            <todo-list
                                    v-for="todo in todos"
                                    v-bind:todo-obj="todo"
                                    v-bind:key="todo.id"
                                    :todo-obj.sync="todo"
                                    v-on:usun="deleteTod"
                                    ></todo-list>
                        </table>

                        <div v-if="isLogged" id="todoText">
                            <textarea v-model="todoText" cols="53" rows="5"></textarea>
                            <div id="addButton">
                                <button v-on:click="addTodo" class="btn btn-success" >Add to do</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div v-else>
                            You have to be
                            <a href="login">Login</a>
                            to add new todos
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my component:

```
Vue.component('todoList', {
props: ['todoObj'],
template: '<tr>' +
'<td><div class="round"><input id="todoObj.id" type="checkbox" v-on:click="toggle" v-model="todoObj.done" /><label for="todoObj.id"></label></div></td>' +
'<td class="textTodo">{{todoObj.description}}</td>' +
'<td><button v-on:click="deleteTodo" class="btn-xs btn-danger">delete</button></td>' +
'</tr>',
```

Also my checkboxes are not working. They look fine, but they don't toggle when I click them, they only react when checking the first row from the table. Why?

Comment: What do you mean by out of the table? Please provide a code example that can be reproduced. Also please limit this thread to one single question.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: What do you have in your todos array?

Comment: show us your main vue template.

Comment: I have objects with my todo  ( it has id, description and done <- for checboxes)

Comment: I edited and added whole template blade

Answer (score 4):

Your table might not be rendering correctly due to [DOM Template Parsing Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats). Try this instead:

```
<table class="table-responsive">
  <tr
    v-for="todo in todos"
    is="todo-list"
    :todo-obj="todo"
    :key="todo.id"
    @usun="deleteTod"
  ></tr>
</table>
```

Also you had the `todoObj` bound twice (I removed the `.sync` one in the above code).

As for the checkbox issue, I'm not completely sure on what the problem is, especially since you have not provided the code for the component (a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/148/) would be great). Why do you have `@toggle` *and* `v-model`? Couldn't you just use `v-model`? You also forgot to `v-bind` to the checkbox's `id` attribute: `id="todoObj.id"` (is that necessary anyway?).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this already answered question because I went around for hours trying to figure out why my component (that was basically a table row) was rendering *before* the `<table>` it was placed in, instead of *within* the `<table>` where I put it.

Instead of doing this like you would intuitively do with most any component:

```
<table>
    <my-table-row-component v-for="row in tablerows"></my-table-row-component>
</table>
```

You need to instead use your component like this:

```
<table>
    <tr is="vue:my-table-row-component" v-for="row in tablerows"></tr>
</table>
```

This will render the table row component where it should be, within the `<table>` tag.

This is covered in the vuejs.org docs at the bottom of the [Components Basics - Element Placement Restrictions](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#element-placement-restrictions)